# subdividing and repotting drosera/sundew

Tags: containers, repotting

I have a very nice drosera/sundew - but it's overgrown it's little container and needs to be repotted.

- What should I use as the potting soil?

I plan on separating it into two or three new containers. Why should I use as containers? Right now it's in the really cheap plastic container it came in.

- Should I use a glass or ceramic pot?

Any other advice for repotting drosera would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What a beautiful plant! Had to look it up and www.growsundews.com/sundews/drosera_nidiformis.html Grin, couldn't seem to copy it so I retyped it here...you'll have to find it again on search.  It talked about repotting, media, pots and propagation. After reading this I wouldn't divide it, just grow it from the seed it produces.  Roots sound pretty fragile where fungus is concerned.  Sterilize the new pot (it should only be a few inches larger!) and I'd use clay. Clay breathes, better for discouraging fungus. Thanks for introducing me to a new plant that is gorgeous!!